# Node Js run build errors can't resolve component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

When i do a `npm run build` I am getting the following error.

```
./pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../components/Nav/Nav' in '/home/webuser/node_site/document/pages'
```

The `components` and `Nav` folder are in the correct location.  Also the `Nav.js` file is also there. I have also tried `../components/Nav/Nav.js` still giving module not found.

Node is version 12.16.2
npm version 6.14.4

Comment: might be a dumb question but is the Nav being exported in Nav.js?

Comment: you need to share `Nav.js` and where you're importing it too so we can see what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok well this is embarrassing. I had caps incorrectly mac doesn't seem to however linux does.  the folder structure is `components/nav/Nav` the code is `../components/Nav/Nav` it compiled just fine on the mac.  Once I changed the code to `../components/nav/Nav` everything worked.